# Need to change element based on size in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, element

I need this

```html
<div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?11123298&data_platform=code&data_date=2017-02-16" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    xProductBrowser("categoriesPerRow=3","views=grid(20,3) list(60) table(60)","categoryView=grid","searchView=list","id=my-store-11123298");
  </script>
</div>
```

to turn into this

```html
<div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?11123298&data_platform=code&data_date=2017-02-16" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    xProductBrowser("categoriesPerRow=3","views=grid(20,1) list(60) table(60)","categoryView=grid","searchView=list","id=my-store-11123298");
  </script>
</div>
```

when browsing on a mobile device. I have seen other stuff on this but none of it worked when I tried. I don't really know much about java script so please be really specific if it's that:)

Comment: Since mobile devices can have a higher resolution than a computer, do you mean below a certain width or height or ...? ... and to start with device detection is not a good idea since there is no really good way doing it

Comment: Didn't get anything. Please, add more details to your question